# Calcular el número de líneas con valores nan

Tags: pandas

Estoy tratando de averiguar cuántas líneas no están limpias.

```
    loan_amnt   term    installment grade   emp_length  home_ownership  annual_inc  addr_state  dti delinq_2yrs ... num_bc_sats num_bc_tl   num_il_tl   num_rev_tl_bal_gt_0 pct_tl_nvr_dlq  percent_bc_gt_75    tot_hi_cred_lim total_bal_ex_mort   total_bc_limit  total_il_high_credit_limit
41131   24000   36 months   757.51  B   1 year  MORTGAGE    80000.0 WA  11.80   0.0 ... 11.0    11.0    29.0    7.0 100.0   9.1 501190.0    167271.0    137400.0    121695.0
41135   8000    36 months   257.39  B   6 years RENT    55000.0 CO  10.16   0.0 ... 4.0 13.0    6.0 4.0 95.7    25.0    27933.0 21907.0 7800.0  17349.0
```

Porque utilisar lo siguiente ?

```
    bad_rows = df.isnull().T.any().T.sum()
```

En vez de `df.isnull().sum()` ? Porque `...T.any().T...` ?

Answer (score 0):

Con 'filas que no están limpias' entiendo que te refieres a que tengan algún `NaN` (por la línea que has puesto para `bad_rows` y el título).

Para entender lo que está pasando, lo mejor es recrearlo con un ejemplo sencillo:

partiendo del siguiente `Dataframe` con 4 filas con elementos `NaN`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[10, 4, 0, 2],
                   [5, np.nan, 3, 6],
                   [7, 4, np.nan, 8],
                   [np.nan, 4, np.nan, 9],
                   [np.nan, 2, 3, 1]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

Al hacer un `print(df.isnull())` nos devolvería la matriz con True en aquellos valores `NaN`:

```
       a      b      c      d
0  False  False  False  False
1  False   True  False  False
2  False  False   True  False
3   True  False   True  False
4   True  False  False  False
```

Si a esto le hiciésemos un `.sum()` nos devolvería la suma de `True` por columnas, es decir:

```
a    2
b    1
c    2
d    0
```

Hacer un `df.isnull().T` para obtener la transpuesta tampoco serviría puesto que en caso de tener más de un NaN en alguna fila también nos saldría un numero mayor al sumar.

Para ello se emplea el metodo [any()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), que devuelve `True` si en un iterable al menos un elemento es `True`.

Aquí abajo puedes ver paso a paso lo que está pasando tal y como lo has puesto:

1. `isnull()` devuelve los elementos `NaN` como `True`.
2. La `T` nos devuelve la transpuesta.
3. `any()` nos dice si hay algún `True` por columna (por eso es
   necesario hacer la Transpuesta.

Dando estos resultados:

```
print(df.isnull())                   print(df.isnull().T)                        print(df.isnull().T.any())

       a      b      c      d               0      1      2      3      4      
0  False  False  False  False        a  False  False  False   True   True        0    False
1  False   True  False  False        b  False   True  False  False  False        1     True
2  False  False   True  False   >>   c  False  False   True   True  False   >>   2     True
3   True  False   True  False        d  False  False  False  False  False        3     True
4   True  False  False  False                                                    4     True
```

Después de este paso ya podrías poner el `sum()`, no siendo necesaria la última `T`.

Por último, después de todo esto, decirte que le puedes pasar al metodo `any()` el parámetro `axis` con valor 1 para que el cálculo lo realice sobre las columnas en vez de las filas, evitando así el hacer la transpuesta:

```
print(df.isnull().any(axis=1).sum())
```